# How to set background colour of a cell in Sheet1, based on the same cell in Sheet2 using Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a Google workbook with the following sheets:
Sheet 1
Sheet 2

I need to be able to color Sheet1 cell A1 to match Sheet2 cell A1 automatically.

For example, if Sheet2 A1 has a green background color, Sheet1 A1 should automatically reflect as green background color as well. If Sheet2 A1 color changes to red, Sheet1 A1 color should change to red as well.

Comment: How you will change `Sheet2 A1` background color? Manually or by CF? If you change color manually then need script.

Comment: Currently it is manual. But we can change it to CF, that will not be an issue.

Sheet2 is basically a sheet plotting our employee's availabilities across the month. We color the cell as green to reflect that they are available. But we can easily change this to "YES" if available, and have a CF color it green.

Comment: Then you can use same CF rule for Sheet1, A1 cell.

Comment: How do i conditional format Sheet1 A1 based on Sheet2 A1's color?

Comment: CF will be based on Active column yes or no. Not based on color. Can you few sample data situated in sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function matchbgs() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg1 = sh1.getRange(1, 1, sh1.getMaxRows(), sh1.getMaxColumns());
  const bg1 = rg1.getBackgrounds();
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const rg2 = sh2.getRange(1, 1, sh2.getMaxRows(), sh2.getMaxColumns());
  const bg2 = rg1.getBackgrounds();
  if (bg1.length <= bg1.length && bg1[0].length <= bg2[0].length) {
    sh2.getRange(rg1.getA1Notation()).setBackgrounds(bg1);
  } else {
    sh2.insertRowsAfter(bg2.length,bg1.length - bg2.length);
    sh2.insertColumnsAfter(bg2[0].length,bg1.length - bg2[0].length);
    sh2.getRange(rg1.getA1Notation()).setBackgrounds(bg1);
  }
}
```